# Spawning Mob Spawner Particles Around a Skeletal Horse in Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Hey so I was just wanting to make a skeletal horse in Minecraft have mob spawner particles around it constantly. I can't figure out how to loop it so that it keeps spawning the fire particles.
What I've done so far is below.

```
package survivalcraft.FireHorse;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse.Variant;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse;
import org.bukkit.Effect;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    public static Main plugin;
    public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
        this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been disabled! Neigh! ;D");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
        this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("firehorse") || commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("fh")){
            Horse horse = (Horse) player.getWorld().spawnEntity(player.getLocation(), EntityType.HORSE);
            horse.setBreed(true);
            horse.setAdult();
            horse.setVariant(Variant.SKELETON_HORSE);
            horse.setCustomName(player.getDisplayName() + "'s Fire Horse");
            horse.getWorld().playEffect(horse.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 0);
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into using [Scheduler Programming](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming). You can create a repeating task that spawns the particles every couple ticks:

```
getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        horse.getWorld().playEffect(horse.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 0);
    }
}, 0L, 10L);
```

Just replace your current `playEffect` line with that, and make `horse` final.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a loop, you should use Bukkit's built-in SchedulerAPI - [explained here](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming).

Here is an example using your code:

**Create a new class called HorseTimer (or whatever you want). Make it implement Runnable class.**

```
public class HorseTimer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

**Then add a constructor so the class knows what entity to spawn the particles around.**

```
public class HorseTimer implements Runnable {
    private Horse horse;

    public HorseTimer(Horse horse) { 
        this.horse = horse; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

**Now you can spawn the particles around the horse (like you would do it once only).**

```
public class HorseTimer implements Runnable {
    private Horse horse;

    public HorseTimer(Horse horse) { 
        this.horse = horse; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do stuff with the horse, will be in the loop.
    }
}
```

**Finally, we need to start the loop in the Main class. Put this code at the end of your if statement in your onCommand(...), method.**

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new HorseTimer(horse), 0l, <DELAY BETWEEN REPEATS IN TICKS HERE>l);
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out the possibility of memory leaks due to storing a Horse entity